# std::thread Why object is copied twice?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why in the example code below, object is copied twice? According documentation constructor of thread class copies all arguments to thread-local storage so we have reason for the first copy. What about second?

```
class A {
public:
    A() {cout << "[C]" << endl;}
    ~A() {cout << "[~D]" << endl;}
    A(A const& src) {cout << "[COPY]" << endl;}
    A& operator=(A const& src) {cout << "[=}" << endl; return *this;}

    void operator() () {cout << "#" << endl;}
};

void foo()
{
    A a;
    thread t{a};
    t.join();
}
```

Output from above:

```
[C]
[COPY]
[COPY]
[~D]
#
[~D]
[~D]
```

Edit: 
Well yes, after adding move constructor:

```
A(A && src) {cout << "[MOVE]" << endl;}
```

The output is like this:

```
[C]
[COPY]
[MOVE]
[~D]
#
[~D]
[~D]
```

Comment: Just a little correction: the arguments are not copied into **thread-local** storage, but onto the new thread's stack. Thread-local storage is a completely different animal; a thread-local variable is, essentially, a per-thread global variable, accessible from any function in the thread, with a distinct copy in each thread.

Comment: In fact, second `[COPY]` is `[MOVE]`, but you can't see it because you have no move constructor implemented.

Comment: In the case above, the second [COPY] is a copy. Only if you provide a move constructor or declare it explicit with = default you get the move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anything you want to move or avoid copies, prefer move constructors and `std::move`.

**But Why doesn't this happen automatically for me?**

Move in C++ is conservative. It generally will only move if you explicitly write `std::move()`. This was done because move semantics, if extended beyond very explicit circumstances, might break older code. Automatic-moves are often restricted to very careful set of circumstances for this reason.

In order to avoid copies in this situation, you need to shift `a` around by using `std::move(a)` (even when passing it into `std::thread`). The reason it makes a copy the first time around is because std::thread can't guarantee that the value will exist after you have finished constructing the std::thread (and you haven't explicitly moved it in). Thusly, it will do the safe thing and make a copy (not take a reference/pointer to what you passed in and store it: the code has no idea whether or not you'll keep it alive or not).

Having both a move constructor and using `std::move` will allow the compiler to maximally and efficiently move your structure. If you're using VC++ (with the CTP or not), you must explicitly write the move constructor, otherwise MSVC will (even sometimes erroneously) declare and use a Copy constructor.

Comment: Of course, if you *will* keep it alive, just use `std::ref()`.

Answer (score 3):

The object is copied twice because the object cannot be *moved*. The standard does not require this, but it is legitimate behavior.

What's happening inside of the implementation is that it seems to be doing a decay_copy of the parameters, as required by the standard. But it doesn't do the decay_copy into the final destination; it does it into some internal, possibly stack, storage. Then it moves the objects from that temporary storage to the final location within the thread. Since your type is not moveable, it must perform a copy.

If you make your type moveable, you'll find that the second copy becomes a move.

Why might an implementation do this, rather than just copying directly into the final destination? There could be any number of implementation-dependent reasons. It may have just been simpler to build a `tuple` of the function+parameters on the stack, then move that into the eventual destination.

Answer (score 0):

try with:     thread t{std::move(a)};