# Passing functor to std::thread by value: Why is copy constructor called twice?

Tags: c++, stdthread

The accepted answer in [std::thread Why object is copied twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990689/stdthread-why-object-is-copied-twice) doesn't answer my question regarding this, so I'm asking here again. **Please** don't mark as duplicate. Here is the code from the link (credit to Krzysztof):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "[C]" << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "[~D]" << endl; }
    A(A const& src) { cout << "[COPY]" << endl; }
    A& operator=(A const& src) {
        cout << "[=}" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()() { cout << "#" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    thread t{a};
    t.join();
}
```

Output from above:

```
[C]
[COPY]
[COPY]
[~D]
#
[~D]
[~D]
```

I know that the `std::thread` blindly copies the arguments passed to it, (unless you use e.g. `std::ref` or `std::move`), so this explains the first copy `ctor`. However, once the arguments are copied into the thread's internal storage, why is the copy `ctor` called again?! Does the functor need to be instantiated twice? Or does it have something to do with the fact that `std::thread` turns the copied arguments into rvalues or something? I'm really lost on this.

Btw, I'm **not** looking for an answer involving move semantics, i.e. I need to implement the move `ctor/pass` with `std::move()`, I want to instead know why, in this specific scenario of passing a functor to the `std::thread ctor` **by value**, the functor's copy `ctor` is called twice. For my use-case, I must pass the functor by value.

Comment: std::thread constructor makes a copy, and then the data is copied to the thread - I guess. Why don't you put a breakpoint in the copy constructor and see who's calling it.

Comment: Since these questions are in fact identical, I've just added an answer that more directly addresses the question of "why" or "what's going on" rather than the question of "how to avoid it".

Comment: @NicolBolas Perfect answer, exactly what I was looking for. I had an inkling the copied arg wasn't directly going to the "final destination". Care to post the answer here so I can accept it as the answer? I upvoted the answer but has no effect b/c I have no rep yet lol. Thanks, and cheers.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I tried that and gained a little bit of insight into what was going on, but not much, there were countless functions being called. I did see the copy ctor being called twice though, by some obscure function. Good suggestion I'll keep in mind for future reference, thanks.

Comment: The call stack will help you to eliminate the STL internal functions.